# Destroying session to logout, but user still logged in until page refreshes

Tags: html, php

I'm using the following code to log users of an application out:

```
session_start(); 
setcookie (session_id(), "", time() - 3600);
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
header("Location: index.php");
```

Afterwards they are sent back to the main page (index.php) of the application. To test they've been successfully logged out I return to another page on the menu which has code to check it the session is active or not. If the session is active, it gets the username and gives them a little hello with the choice to logout.

After logging out initially the main page (index.php) doesn't show the welcome message above, but clicking on a page I had visited logged in before does, but the user isn't really logged in. If I hit F5, the logged in message is cleared and the content they see as a logged in user isn't available. So there appears to be some caching.

I've added the following headers to each page to try force the browser to not cache content:

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
session_start();
```

But no luck :(

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with IE7 allowing users to "browse" a website from which they had already been logged out.

Have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

I ended up with the following (for me) working combination:

```
session_cache_limiter ('private_no_expire, must-revalidate');
```

Comment: Had fingers crossed. But that doesn't seem to have solved it. Have this in the head of each document now:

`header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
session_start();
session_cache_limiter ('private_no_expire, must-revalidate');`

Comment: As session_cache_limiter also sets the "Cache-Control" & "Last Modified" it looks like you are ending up with double headers that might negate each other? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are destroying the session alright, but you still have a client side cookie which you set which is not being destroyed. 
Cookies are different then sessions I believe.

Comment: I'm not setting any cookies. I didn't think a cookie was set by sessions unless specifically stated?

Comment: is this not setting a cookie ? setcookie (session_id(), "", time() - 3600);

Answer (score 0):

Try `unset()` or `session_unset()` function to unset the individual `session variables` rather than only `session_destroy()`. This way is more efficient i guess.

Please browse the following link for detail information

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Answer (score 0):

Check session by $_SESSION['yourSessionName'] OR print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Yep, though not surprised here. If I go to the page it shows:

Array ( [signed_in] => 1 [userid] => 1 [username] => tester [firstname] => tester ) 

Which is to be expected. But if I refresh the page the session is dropped. And nothing is there, just Array ( ) - as it should be.

Comment: `session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");`